# Can I configure a gitlab CI job with a dependency on a manual job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I do this:

```
job1:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  script:
    - daddaa

job1_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies: [job1]
  script:
    - do things to deploy
```

It just fails because `job1_deploy` was started even though the `job1` was not manually started.

Is there a correct way to configure `job1_deploy` started automatically when `job1` was manually started and passed?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if you want `job1` to be a blocking manual action. From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#whenmanual):

> If you want to make manual action blocking, it is necessary to add
>   allow_failure: false to the job’s definition in .gitlab-ci.yml.

So in your case, this should do the trick:

```
job1:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - daddaa

job1_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies: [job1]
  script:
    - do things to deploy
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to start this job only on specific occasions and manually, and that the deployment is then started automatically.  I do not want it to block the pipeline.

Comment: HI @Rekovni, Is it possible to use a stage name instead of the job name to make a job dependent on another job? That is, instead of using "job1" can I by any chance use "build"?

Answer (score 2):

I opened this bug report: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/32552, don't forget to upvote.

As a workaround which does not solve the problem but at least explains it to the developer, we do the following:

1. `job1` writes an extra file, e.g. "testResult.txt", containing "success" or "failure" depending on the job state.
2. `job1` lists this file in its artifacts
3. `job1_deploy` then, in it's `before_script`, checks for existence of this file and if not available, explains the problem and fails the job.

Below is an excerpt from a python script we use.

- FYI 1: Our jobs are called `nightly` and `deploy`.
- FYI 2: We have an environment variable `IGNORE_NIGHTLY_TEST` which can be set before running manually. I did not delete these lines from the excerpt, maybe it is useful to you.

```
  # Hidden knowledge: you can ignore the test check
  # by defining environment variable IGNORE_NIGHTLY_TEST
  ignoreTest = "IGNORE_NIGHTLY_TEST" in os.environ
  try:
    content = open('testResult.txt', 'r').readline()
  except (OSError, IOError) as e:
    print("-" * 100)
    if ignoreTest:
      print("  Nightly tests did not run, but allow deployment due to environment variable IGNORE_NIGHTLY_TEST")
    else:
      print("  Nightly tests did not run, you have to start them MANUALLY before deployment is possible."
        + "\n  Go back to this pipeline's overview and press play for nightlytest."
        + "\n  This is a Gitlab bug: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/32552")
    print("-" * 100)
    sys.exit(0 if ignoreTest else 1)
  if content != 'success':
    print("+" * 100)
    if ignoreTest:
      print("  Nightly tests ran unsuccessfully, but allow deployment due to environment variable IGNORE_NIGHTLY_TEST")
    else:
      print("  Nightly tests ran but they were unsuccessful. Cannot deploy")
    print("+" * 100)
    sys.exit(0 if ignoreTest else 1)
```